# Banned from asking

Tags: support, ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-thi)

Where can I get the reason for having been banned for asking questions on Stack Overflow? I haven't found any reason for this, and I haven't yet found any Internet resource where user can be banned without any explanation, so I think such a good site like Stack Overflow has a page where I can read administrators' doings connected to me.

Comment: What message do you get?

Comment: Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.

Comment: have you tried to click on that link?

Comment: @MatthiasBauch yes but it has not helped me to answer my question

Comment: According to [this Data explorer query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/59824/aleksey-http-meta-stackoverflow-com-questions-119837-banned-for-asking), your account seems OK. I guess that you're a victim of someone else's deeds (=IP ban).

Comment: @Rob W but that query doesn't include deleted posts, does it? With every complaint about the question block I've ever seen on Meta, it later turns out the OP had a huge percentage of downvoted and deleted contributions.

Comment: @Pekka'sOrganicRepFarm Late response, but I just recalled that I once recovered a deleted answer on MSO via the Data Explorer. So, it *does* include deleted posts, but not the newest ones.

Comment: I'm in the same boat as Aleksey on stackoverflow. Dunno what happened, was working fine before...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You keep on deleting questions you ask. That is poor practice. If you ask something, let the loop be closed and let others answer you. If you get no answer, you can always answer it yourself.

To avoid asking dupes, search well before asking.

Also, take some time and provide awesome answers.

Your case is borderline, the ban will most likely be lifted if you contribute one or 2 awesome answers, you are clearly capable of providing.

Comment: *"You keep on deleting questions you ask. That is poor practice."* and Aleksey, this is actually mentioned with its own heading in [that FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-thi/86998#86998). Sure, that answer is long, but I think it's up to the question-banned user to read it two or three times if needed, read the linked resources, and then figure out what got them banned.